# dpkg shows a curious syntax error while installing a package

Tags: package-management, dpkg, python3, syntax

While installing Brightness Controller from its [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~apandada1/+archive/ubuntu/brightness-controller) in Ubuntu 20.04, it shows an invalid syntax error

```
Setting up brightness-controller (2.3.4-0~202004250741~ubuntu20.04.1) ...
  File "/usr/share/brightness-controller/util/write_config.py", line 21
    def _default_config(config, display_type: str = 'primary'):
                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: error processing package brightness-controller (--configure):
 installed brightness-controller package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 101
```

However, when I run the python file directly from the [source code](https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness/), it does not show any error. Despite showing this error during installation, the program does install, and runs correctly and does not print any syntax error (when called from terminal) when the relevant functions of write_config.py is called.

Any idea why dpkg shows an syntax error of a Python file and Python itself does not show any error? And how to fix it?

Comment: Note: I am the package maintainer of this software, and I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Looks like a python2 versus python3 issue to me (the `:` introduces a [function annotation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/#syntax) )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that dpkg does not recognize `str`, and [removing this typehint](https://github.com/LordAmit/Brightness/commit/b191b06b42247c802897fafba6fcc515971ef845) fixed the error.